# How can I separate tokens in Java when there are some null tokens

Tags: java, parsing, csv

i have line in .csv file as
 abc,bcc,

i have to separate it into three tokens as abc   bcc  and  null

first i had try stringTokenizer but it will not return null token so
after that i try string.split(",") but it will not return the last null string
it will return string which has null in between but not at last

so please help me
 thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [the `String.split()` variant that takes a limit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) and pass a negative number to it.

Answer (score 2):

use the two argument split with a negative second argument

```
String str = "abc,bcc,";
String[] tokens = str.split(",", -1);
```

[split(String, int) documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))